# Python C++ API function with multiple arguments

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a python module using my C++ code and I want to declare a function with multiple arguments. (3 in this case) I've read the docs and it says that I must declare `METH_VARARGS` which I did, but I think I also must change something inside my function to actually receive the arguments. Otherwise it gives me "too many arguments" error when I use my function in python.

Here is the code snippet I'm using:

```
...
// This function can be called inside a python file.
static PyObject *
call_opencl(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    const char *command;
    int sts;

    // We except at least one argument to this function
    // Not sure how to accept more than one.
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &command))
        return NULL;

    OpenCL kernel = OpenCL();
    kernel.init();

    std::cout << "This message is called from our C code: " << std::string(command) << std::endl;

    sts = 21;

    return PyLong_FromLong(sts);
}

static PyMethodDef NervebloxMethods[] = {
    {"call_kernel",          call_opencl,         METH_VARARGS,              "Creates an opencv instance."},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}        /* Sentinel */
};

...
```

Answer (score 2):

You are still expecting one argument.

```cpp
if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &command))
```

the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html) defines how you can expect optional or additional arguments, for example "s|dd" will expect a string and two optional numbers, you still have to pass two doubles to the function for when the numbers are available.

```cpp
double a = 0; // initial value
double b = 0;
if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s|dd", &command, &a, &b))
```